# Mouse Leaves Dark Souls III Window

Tags: windows-10, mouse

The purpose of this post is to inquire about a Windows 10 setting to lock the mouse inside of the game window.

Whether I play in full screen or windowed, the cursor seems to delight in going out of screen. Upon click, I'm effectively alt-tabbed out of the game.

Unfortunately, the use of 3rd party programs will invariably result in a ban for the game I'm attempting to enjoy; As a matter of fact, bans have been notoriously distributed indiscriminately for reasons ranging from cheating to other sorts of modification that can be detected by the game.

Is there a solution to my problem or am I out of options?

Comment: Are you sure you are playing in full screen, and not full-screen windowed mode?  Only programs that allow you to cheat in the game will get you banned.

Comment: True full screen which launches to default monitor window, yes. Presently, I have it running in windowed mode though or else it'll minimize the program when clicking outside.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer a
[AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/)
solution:

Create an AutoHotKey script in a file named `yourname.ahk` with these contents :

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
F1:WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, On, Dark Souls
F2:WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, Off, Dark Souls
```

It is assumed that the text "Dark Souls" appears in the title of the game's window.

I have chosen here the F1 key to set Dark Souls to always on top,
and F2 to set it to off,
but you may choose any [other keys](https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm).

To test the file, double-click it to launch. Notice that it will have a green "H" icon in the traybar, which you may right-click to exit while testing.

Once it is proven as working, place it in your Startup folder.

However, this does traffic the attributes of the window, so could conceivably be picked up by the game.

---

You could also set the Windows option of
"Activate a window by hovering over it with the mouse",
which is an attribute of Windows and so has nothing to do with the game
process.

This option is found in
*Control Panel > Ease of Access Center > Make the mouse easier to use*

---

Otherwise, all I can offer is to get [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and set higher the priority of the game, which will give it some advantage over other processes.

Comment: DARK SOULS III in the window but yes, you assumed correctly. I don't feel comfortable using this solution since it involves using a script which targets the window. It could be safe but people were getting banned for programs running in the background doing similar seemingly innocuous tweaks.

Comment: You may be right. I have added some other possibilities.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't appear as though those methods will work the way I'd like (which is to lock the mouse inside the window). From what I've noticed, this is a prevalent issue in many newer PC game titles. It's cute that someone -1'd my post when in actuality it is a real issue.

In addition to this, I never would have known about 3rd party programs if I hadn't performed at least a little work... Sadly, both my knowledge from prior experimentation and current research didn't yield a solution. I appreciate you trying to help...

Answer (score 0):

Having more than one monitor when playing some games can tend to cause a tab out when the mouse is moved in the direction of another monitor. While in Windowed mode, the potential for tabbing out is increased multiplicativly depending on the size of the window (full screen windowed can still potentially hit the taskbar).

Disconnecting any additional monitors and playing full screen seems to be the only effective solution.